# Matching a String in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string say like this:

```
  ARAN22 SKY BYT and TRO_PAN
```

In the above string The first alphabet can be A or S or T or N and the two numbers after RAN can be any two digit. However the rest will be always same and last three characters will be always like _PAN.

So the few possibilities of the string are :

```
  SRAN22 SK BYT and TRO_PAN
  TRAN25 SK BYT and TRO_PAN
  NRAN25 SK BYT and TRO_PAN
```

So I was trying to extract the string every time in python using regex as follows:

```
import re

pattern =   "([ASTN])RAN" + "\w+\s+" +"_PAN"

pat_check = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

sample_test_string = 'NRAN28 SK BYT and TRO_PAN'

re.match(pat_check, sample_test_string)
```

here string can be anything like the above examples I gave there.

But its not working as I am not getting the string name ( the sample test string) which I should. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where does your regex attempt to handle the digits?

Comment: What does "I am not getting the string name " mean?

Comment: @Scott I was expecting when I run re.match(pat_check, sample_test_string) , I should be getting the sample-test_string: 'NRAN28 SK BYT and TRO_PAN'. But instead when I run the code, I get None

Comment: `pattern =   "([ASTN])RAN" + "\w+\s+" +"_PAN"` To pick just one example of how the pattern is wrong, it demands that `_PAN` is immediately preceded by a space, which your sample string clearly does not have.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon I see. Yeah I was trying  "([ASTN])RAN" +"\w+" + "\s+" +"TRO_PAN", too, but it fails too as expected and mentioned by you. So then I have to put all the string with spaces for the regex to work?

Comment: try `pattern=r'([ASTN])RAN\d+[\w ]+TRO_PAN'` - the parentheses `()` around the first letter make it the first capture group. Also note `\w` will match `_`  and numbers, regex is greedy if you pass is many of these in one long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `\w+\s+`, which will match one or more word (`0-9A-Za-z_`) characters, followed by one or more space characters. So it will match the two digits and space after `RAN` but then nothing more. Since the next characters are not `_PAN`, the match will fail. You need to use `[\w\s]+` instead:

```py
pattern =   "([ASTN])RAN" + "[\w\s]+" +"_PAN"
```

Comment: oh wonderful. Thats sweet. Thank you @Nick! I learned something new!

Comment: Since you seem to be expert in regex, one more quick help: if my string is like: 'NRAN'28 SK BYT and TRO_PAN' with an apostrophe in between RAN and the number how can I extract that? I was trying  "([ASTN])" + + "\'" + "RAN" + "[\w\s]+" +"_PAN". But that does not seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: You have the apostrophe in the wrong place in your pattern, it should be after `RAN` i.e. `pattern = "([ASTN])" + "RAN" + "'" + "[\w\s]+" +"_PAN"` Note you don't need a backslash before the `'`.

Comment: oh Nick you are awesome! Thanks for pointing my error. I was continuosly scratching my head!